# Register Endpoint on Cisco ISE with RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, cisco

I'm trying to register(POST) an Endpoint on an Cisco ISE 1.3 via the RestSharp Client in a C# Console Application.

I already got it working with GET requests. 
The code i used:

```
String XML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?> <ns3:endpoint name='name' id='id' description='Desc' xmlns:ns2='ers.ise.cisco.com'    xmlns:ns3='identity.ers.ise.cisco.com'> <groupId>04f3c120-f42f-11e2-bd54-005056bf2f0a</groupId> <mac>00:00:CC:Ac:BB:CC</mac> <profileId>576bf7b0-f42f-11e2-bd54-005056bf2f0a</profileId><staticGroupAssignment>true</staticGroupAssignment> <staticProfileAssignment>true</staticProfileAssignment> </ns3:endpoint> "; 
var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://" + ip + ":9060/ers/config/endpoint");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(user, pw);

var request = new RestRequest(); 
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.endpoint.1.0+xml");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.endpoint.1.0+xml; charset=utf-8");
    request.AddBody(XML);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    request.XmlSerializer.ContentType = "application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.endpoint.1.0+xml; charset=utf-8";

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I submit the Code I receive a **"Unsuported Media-Type"** error.
The Headers are taken from the SDK from Cisco.
I already realized it with curl, SharePoint and SC Orchestrator.

I think that there is a mistake in the combination of the XML to the request but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the content type in the headers, it is the same as the accept one:

request.Method = Method.GET; request.AddHeader("Accept",application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.guestuser.2.0+xml"); request.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.guestuser.2.0+xml");